# jQuery AJAX jsonp can't work with the response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

So, I wrote a WordPress plugin to generate a JSON file with the latest X articles, which after it may be accessed from a URL, that is being cached with CloudFront.

So, I access my file like so (in a browser): http://mm.site.com/wp-content/uploads/plug/plug.json

And I get my JSON format response file:

```
{"id":55142,"title":"Un nuevo modelo productivo para Espa\u00f1a","url": ....
```

Now, this is the js code I use to access the file in a async mode:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mm.site.com/wp-content/uploads/plug/plug.json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});

jqXHR.done(function(json) {
       console.log(json);
    })
    .error(function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    })
    .always(function(test) {
        console.log(test);
    });
```

Now, the curios part is that under the Network tab (Firebug, or Chrome dev tools), I see the request and it ends up with a `200 Status Code` and the file contents, BUT, I can't see the response in `.done()`, so I can't access and work with it.

Any ideas why that might be?

### Update

`json` instead of `jsonp`, won't do it due to `cross-origin control`. Remember that I server the file from Amazon's CloudFront. I tried fixing that, but with no luck, so unless you have another option, I have no other choice but to use `jsonp`

Comment: Change `jsonp` to `json` and try it.

Comment: can't, due to `cross-origin control`

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the server returns JSONP, i.e. `func(...data...);`. You get JSON as response which won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: as @Felix Kling  notes, `done` does register the function as a callback, the main callback is a jQuery handler that looks like:

```
?callback=jQuery19104353667694941068_1372008424415&foo=bar
```

A static file won't be able to respond properly to this call as `jQuery` generates the handler name dynamically.

Setting `jsonpCallback: "fixedName"` will work if the static file is in the form `fixedName({ .. some variable ..})`.

---

Original response:

`jsonp` doesn't fire `done` method. It appends a `script` tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://anothersite.com/?callback=whatToDoWhenDone"></script>
```

The expected response will be JS code that will call `whatToDoWhenDone` and the JSON object as arguments:

```
whatToDoWhenDone({"id":55142,"title":"Un nuevo modelo productivo para Espa\u00f1a","url": .... });
```

If you don't need to use `jsonp`, just change it to `json`.

Comment: You are wrong, jQuery resolves the promise even for JSONP: http://jsfiddle.net/GLTkW/.